# HiveSQL - Invalid column reference

Tags: sql, hive

I get the error

> [Code: 10002, SQL State: 42000]
> Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10002]: Line 11:60 Invalid column reference 'FIELD3'

when running the following query:

```
CREATE TABLE NEW_TABLE 
AS
    SELECT 
        T1.*,
        T2.*,
        T3.*
    FROM 
        OLD_TABLE1 T1
    LEFT JOIN 
        OLD_TABLE2 T2 ON (T1.FIELD1 = T2.FIELD1)
    LEFT JOIN 
        OLD_TABLE3 T3 ON (T1.FIELD3 = T3.FIELD3);
```

What is the potential issue of the above query? I double checked that the `FIELD3` exists in `OLD_TABLE1` and `OLD_TABLE3`.

Comment: What column names do you expect in the NEW_TABLE if  T1, T2, T3  contain columns named the same and you selecting all *

Comment: Thanks for reply. You are right, I should have limit selecting either one of the same column name from either T1 or T3 from the select statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One major issue you have is that duplicated column names in the table.  At the very least, the `JOIN` conditions will introduce duplicates.  There might be other duplicates as well.

List the columns you want *explicitly*:

```
CREATE TABLE NEW_TABLE AS
    SELECT . . .    -- list column names explicitly
    FROM OLD_TABLE1 T1 LEFT JOIN
         OLD_TABLE2 T2
         ON T1.FIELD1 = T2.FIELD1 LEFT JOIN
         OLD_TABLE3 T3
         ON T1.FIELD3 = T3.FIELD3;
```

This problem may occur with `CREATE TABLE`.  That said, it is more common with aggregation queries.